# How to Read JSON file and Modify JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/Wg2Yb/
It basically reads a local file (.txt, .json...) and displays the content.

I want to be able to have it not only read, but also modify some things. 
I have a JSON file that looks a bit like this:

```
{ "height":100,
 "layers":[
        {
         "data":[0, 0, 0, 0...];
         "height":100,
         ...
        }
}
```

I want to know how to modify my page's JQuery based on that. 
Like if the layers height is set to 100 in the JSON file, It would do something like:

```
$('#map').css('height','100px');
```

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: I'm sorry for not having been clear...I would like to know how to modify my page's JQuery based on a JSON file's data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to turn the data into something more javascript friendly.

With that you can save the result to a Javascript object and check for properties/array values and manipulate HTML elements:

```
var data = JSON.parse(this.result);
if (data.layers && data.layers.length && data.layers[0].height) {
    document.getElementById('map').style.height = data.layers[0].height + 'px';
}
```

Check it out on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/tL2Lw/).